# thymeleaf resolved variable

Tags: java, thymeleaf

i would like to know, if it's possible to use a resolved variable as a getter name for an object.

Like:

```
   <div th:with="finalObject = ${rowentry.${tdentry}} >
              <p th:text="${finalObject}">object</p>
   </div>
```

with `${tdentry}` like "key" or "value"

so i will get entry.key and that will be resolved to `rowEntry.getKey()` in my java object `rowEntry`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One needs to be very careful with this kind of construction, as you can run into trouble very quickly if `${tdentry}` doesn't have one of the values you expect. Generally, the way to approach this kind of thing is just to have a variable storing the key, a variable storing the value, and then use a conditional like `th:if` to pick which one. That may look a bit wordier, but can at least be clearly correct and obvious to somebody looking at the code later what's going on.

But the feature you're asking for in Thymeleaf is called "[Preprocessing](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing)". You can use something like this:

```
<div th:with="finalObject=${rowentry.__${tdentry}__}">
```

The expression within the double-underscores is evaluated first, and then the result is used in the main expression. A very powerful tool, and I have used it on occasion, but it can lead to some confusion (and like other dynamically-generated code, security vulnerabilities if you're not careful).

Comment: worked. And thanks for mention the security concerns. So maybe i will use your first suggestion.